# Generate shadow in android for dialog window

Tags: android

I would like to ask about generating the shadow for the following requirement in android:

1. color: #000000, opacity: 12
2. x: 0, Y: 4, blur: 12

I saw the there is shadowColor, shadowDx, shadowDy, shadowRadius.

```
<item name="android:shadowColor">#1F000000</item>
<item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
<item name="android:shadowDy">4</item>
<item name="android:shadowRadius">12</item>
```

I think there is no blur item to set. But shadowRadius seems not the one that i want.

Can i help me explaining what these means? Totally not familiar with these terms.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to implement shadow for an AlertDialog?

Comment: Yes, i want to make shadow for the AlertDialog with the color, x,y pos and blur value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41718953/7461132 might solve your problem