# Drop shadow blur effect on a FrameLayout / Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-paint, android-blur-effect

I'm trying to make a drop shadow blur effect WITH COLOR on a rectangular layout view. I've tried to use this code but to no avail.

```
    int glowRadius = 14;

    int glowColor = Color.parseColor("#acc5fe");

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(glowColor);

    paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(glowRadius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.OUTER));
    RectF rectF = new RectF(mRootView.getHeight(), mRootView.getWidth(),
            mRootView.getHeight(), mRootView.getWidth());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.drawRect(rectF, paint);
    mRootView.draw(canvas);
```

It doesn't seem to do anything though.
I also tried to use shadowDx and shadowDy etc. but that does nothing.

[How to add a blurred drop shadow to a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674828/how-to-add-a-blurred-drop-shadow-to-a-button) is a very similar question but I don't think the 9-patch is a viable solution since it's a layout and not an image.

**How do you create a drop outer shadow blur effect on Android?**

**Update**

Still haven't found a successful answer. I want something like

[image: example blur]

where the shadow effect is on the email edittext with a different color than black.

Answer (score 0):

> try following A library for supporting convex material shadows

https://github.com/harjot-oberai/MaterialShadows

Comment: how do you change the color though?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is first you want to drop a shadow. Here is what you can do to drop a shadow.
Just add this to your parent layout in xml.

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

Check this answer for more information.
[how to add shadow effect in alert dialog box in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715741/how-to-add-shadow-effect-in-alert-dialog-box-in-android#43254243)
Let me know if this works for you.

Edit:
Please check this answer. This might help you.
[Extending Android View class to add a dropshadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930984/extending-android-view-class-to-add-a-dropshadow)
It can be achieved using [NinePatchDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable). Below is a simple example.

```
  protected NinePatchDrawable bg;
  protected Paint paint;
  protected Rect padding = new Rect();
  protected Bitmap bmp;

      protected void init() {
        // decode the 9patch drawable
        bg = (NinePatchDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.balloon);

        // get paddings from the 9patch and apply them to the View
        bg.getPadding(padding);
        setPadding(padding.left, padding.top, padding.right, padding.bottom);

        // prepare the Paint to use below
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        // this check is needed in order to get this code
        // working if target SDK>=11
        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 )
          setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);

        // set the shadowLayer
        paint.setShadowLayer(
          padding.left * .2f, // radius
          0f, // blurX
          padding.left * .1f, // blurY
          Color.argb(128, 0, 0, 0) // shadow color
        );
      }
```

Also please try this color:

```
Color.argb(128, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: i need a specific color though like #acc5fe

Comment: Please set shadow color using `paint.setShadowLayout` instead of `int glowColor = Color.parseColor("#acc5fe");`

Comment: @John61590 like the one link states `Extending Android View class to add a dropshadow`. So create a new class called `MyLayout` and extend it to, lets say, `LinearLayout`, now create the method called `init()` and call `myLayout.init()` programatically.